# 2D array error in python using scikitlearn package

Tags: python, numpy, seaborn

i have used  following code in my pycharm but i am constantly getting the error mentioned below:

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn import linear_model
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df=pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\gmcks\Downloads\Data samples\homeprices.csv")

df
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wxaadKAHTZtECv6gW6Mpreq3tFb2PWgVOhqANbWlIAk/edit?usp=sharing

x=df[["area"]]
y=df.price
reg=linear_model.LinearRegression()
reg.fit(x,y)
LinearRegression()
m=reg.coef_
c=reg.intercept_
print(m,c)
reg.predict(2000)

ERROR :

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\gmcks\PycharmProjects\using jupyter.py\venv\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3319, in run_code
        exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
      File "<ipython-input-30-b5b06b1b028e>", line 1, in <module>
        reg.predict(2000)
      File "C:\Users\gmcks\PycharmProjects\using jupyter.py\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\_base.py", line 236, in predict
        return self._decision_function(X)
      File "C:\Users\gmcks\PycharmProjects\using jupyter.py\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\_base.py", line 218, in _decision_function
        X = check_array(X, accept_sparse=['csr', 'csc', 'coo'])
      File "C:\Users\gmcks\PycharmProjects\using jupyter.py\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 72, in inner_f
        return f(**kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\gmcks\PycharmProjects\using jupyter.py\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 616, in check_array`enter code here`
        "if it contains a single sample.".format(array))
    ValueError: Expected 2D array, got scalar array instead:
    array=2000.
    Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

Why do I have to shape my data again as I have already written the code as `df[["area"]]`? This piece of code converts the array into (5,1), so 2D array is created.

Comment: The error is in `reg.predict(2000)`.  It's complaining about a `scalar array`.  I would call `np.array(2000)` a scalar array, not a 2d array!   Trying the same thing over and over again isn't going get rid of the error.

Comment: try `reg.predict([[2000]])`

Comment: If possible and you want to create a reproducible example, it is better to not link to external sources like your google doc. You'll have more success if you can paste the data or a sample of the data into your dataframe. I appreciate this might be more challenging for data visualization as it can change the way your graphs look if you use sample data, so perhaps not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the input that is the same shape as your predictor:

```
from sklearn import linear_model
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(111)

df = pd.DataFrame({'x' : np.random.uniform(0,1,100),
                   'y' : np.random.uniform(0,1,100)})

reg=linear_model.LinearRegression()
reg.fit(df[["x"]],df['y'])
```

You can do:

```
reg.predict([[2000]])
```